# Install xdebug on Debian without updating PHP

Tags: dependencies, debian, xdebug

I'm trying to install xdebug on a Debian squeeze with PHP 5.3.9. Both the `php5-xdebug` package and `php-dev` (which has `phpize`, which is necessary for manual installation) are based on PHP 5.3.13. How can I install xdebug if I do not want to update the PHP version? (I tried to build PHP manually to get `phpize`, but ended up in dependency hell with libxml and libssh and whatnot missing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no probs, i guess. I have php 5.3.3-7+squeeze9 installed, just downloaded php5-xdebug (2.1.0-1) from http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/php5-xdebug and dpkg -i'd it - no hicups. Maybe your apt configuration is screwed up?

Edit: Sorry, now i see that xdebug depends on phpapi-20090626+lfs (or phpapi-20090626 without +lfs, depending on the architecture), but i dunno which api your 5.3.9 provides. Find out with

```
dpkg -s php5-cgi | grep ^Provides:
```

or one of

```
dpkg -s php5-cli | grep ^Provides:
dpkg -s plibapache2-mod-php5 | grep ^Provides:
dpkg -s plibapache2-mod-php5filter | grep ^Provides:
```

and then find the right version of xdebug for it.

Comment: The api is 20090626+lfs as you said. The `php5-xdebug` depends on the specific php version though: `aptitude show php5-xdebug | grep ^Depends:` gives ` libc6(>= 2.4), php5-common (= 5.3.13-1~dotdeb.0)`. This is a preconfigured virtual box so it might have nonstandard configuration; the problem is that I am unfamiliar with apt and have no idea where to start checking.

Comment: Well, then leave apt alone. Download the .deb from http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/php5-xdebug and install with "dpkg -i".